# Specman e UVM: Why to inherit from uvm_* units?

Tags: uvm, specman, e

I'm implementing a verification environment according to `e UVM user guide`.

My question is - why should `my_monitor` unit to inherit from `uvm_monitor` (same for other UVM components)?

What exactly logic do every `uvm_*` have? Can I implement UVM environment without inheriting from `uvm_*` units?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - yes, since 99% of the advanced capabilities are part of Specman and not in a library, you can implement UVM environment without loading the UVM-e.

The UVM-e contains VR_AD, Testflow, Scoreboard, Low Power, Unit testing, UVM-debug-window. If you do not care to use any of these - no need to import UVM-e.

About the UVM base types - there is a no big reason to use them. The main reason is for other tools to be able to parse the environment and recognize that a specific unit is like a UVM base type. A linter is an example of an advance tool that can care about things like this (and then report that "you have a monitor without a port" and things like that).